# Html popup window redirect to webpage

Tags: html, popupwindow

Would like a pop up box with a question. If user press YES, they will be sent to mydomain.com. If they press NO they will be sent to yourdomain.com.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the browser's built-in confirmation box.

```
if (confirm('Switch?')) {
  location.href = 'mydomain.com';
} else {
  location.href = 'yourdomain.com';
};
```

If you want it customized and in HTML, then your question is far too broad.